# Do I have to download Android Studio if I am already using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am already using IntelliJ IDEA. Do I have to download all the Android Studio files (almost 1 GB)?

Can't I just download the SDK and continue on developing?

Comment: Is It Really Necessary To Capitalize All Words?

Comment: The EAP of IntelliJ 13 has all of the Android Studio features except for the new project wizard and App Engine cloud endpoints integration. IntelliJ 12 doesn't have these features, so it depends on which version you are using currently.

Comment: Well I Like CamelCase :)

Comment: I Am Using Ultimate Edition 14.0.4

Comment: I think you should. Android Studio is better for specifically Android development. Better integration of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download only the SDK. You can find the download link [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other), under "SDK Tools Only".

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this: IntelliJ IDEA's Android plugin does not always have all the latest Android-specific features, developed by Google, that are already in Android Studio.

IDEA is fine too, but if you seriously do Android, just get Android Studio, you'll be better off with it.

(I use—and love—IntelliJ IDEA too for backend & web development. Having both installed is no problem. Who cares about 1 GB of disk space.)

Comment: Hahaha... It's Not The Disk Space I Am Talking About.... It's My Net... Damn Slow. Huge Problem :(

Comment: Thanks All,
I'll Just Download The Whole Thing To Be On The Safe Side :)